# What should be put in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for CF dist and route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have Cloud Front distribution URL (`https://abcdef.cloudfront.net/`) backed by Route53 (`https://example.com`).

I need to set '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header - I am not allowed to put `'*'` here.

So the question is whether to put the Cloud Front distribution URL or the Route53 URL.
I am not sure which one will work, or either one will work?

A bit more context:

So I have a full-stack application - The UI part is build and copied to a S3 bucket which is then linked to the above Cloudfront Distribution (`https://abcdef.cloudfront.net/`).
This particular Cloudfront distribution is then backed by a hosted zone DNS via Route 53 (`https://example.com`).

I have multiple back-end AWS Lambdas hiding behind an AWS API Gateway which has an Integration Request as Type: LAMBDA_PROXY.

The headers are part of the response of the Lambdas, as below:

```
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
 'X-XSS-Protection': '1',
 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
```

The Security scan is raising the below issue:

**Risk Name**

Overly Permissive CORS Access Policy

**Vulnerability**

Scan detected that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is too permissive.

**Threat**

- It is possible to gather sensitive information about the web
  application such as usernames, passwords, machine name and/or
  sensitive file locations
- It is possible to persuade a naive user to supply sensitive
  information such as username, password, credit card number, social
  security number etc.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact you use the LAMBDA_PROXY request type behind API Gateway, your lambda function is responsible for returning the correct headers. I suggest the following:

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type", // check API Gateway configuration which headers are allowed by default
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com", // you add the domain which is used to make the request
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
};
```

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: I added some context, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, I updated my answer. I hope I was able to assist in resolving your issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: so just to zero down to the answer. `you add the domain which is used to make the request` -> should it be cloud front URL or Routre 53 URL?

Comment: The domain you typed in your browser, it might even be both.